# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Tags: runtime-error, discord.js

I'm making a clear command in discord.js **AND I DO KNOW THERE IS ANOTHER DUPLICATE** but for some reason that **DUPLICATE** question doesn't solve my answer

```
    else if(command == "clear")
    {
        async function clear(){
            let fetched;
            do {
                fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 100});
                message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
                message.delete()
            }
            while(fetched.size >= 2)
          }
          clear();
    }
```

and the title is the error I got

Comment: The last statement in the first iteration of your loop is `message. delete()`. The first statement in the second iteration of your loop is `await message.channel....` How would that work, if you already deleted your message? And that's also what the error message is telling you. The message you are trying to operate on is not known to the API (because you previously deleted it) You probalby want to delete the message only after all related messages have been deleted, ie outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

To delete messages no need to fetch them.
You can just write

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(100,true).then(msg=>{
console.log(`${msg.size} is deleted!`)
}).catch(err=>{
console.log(err)
})
```

The second parameter is to filter the 2 weeks old messages. More can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/NewsChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete)